# Нарахування і зарахування

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Поясніть мені, будь ласка, різницю між словами **«нарахування»** та **«зарахування»**. Чи вони є тотожними? Зауважу, що *йдеться про на-/зарахування коштів на рахунки.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Зарахувати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?wordid=31970&page=1035) — це загалом, коли кого/щось починають вважати належним до певної категорії, представників якої тією чи іншою мірою обліковують. Наприклад:

- можна зарахувати до складу якоїсь організації/колективу/групи (тобто почати вважати членом організації/колективу/групи, зареєструвати як члена організації/колективу/групи);
- можна зарахувати до якоїсь абстрактної категорії, якщо та категорія реально чи уявно обліковується (зарахувати до числа зниклих безвісти, зарахувати до Оксаниних коханців, зарахувати до безхребетних підлабузників);
- можна вживати без уточнення, до чого саме зараховуємо, і тоді це сприймається приблизно як «зарахувати дійсним» (зарахувати диплом, зарахувати грошовий переказ, зарахувати перемогу/поразку).

Відповідно, [зарахування](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?wordid=31972&page=1035#lid_31972) — це коли когось/щось зараховують (у будь-якому значенні).

[Нарахувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/narakhovuvaty) має кардинально різні значення, які я не можу охарактеризувати однією фразою:

1. Нарахувати може означати, що коли хтось щось буквально рахував (чи лічив) і отримав певний результат (він рахував (лічив) птахів, що пролітати, і нарахував 237; він рахував (розраховував), скільки прибутку має отримати після виконання роботи, і нарахував 35927 грн).
2. Нараховувати (лише недоконана форма) фігурально може означати «мати в своєму складі» (отара нараховує 76 голів).
3. Нарахувати комусь чи на щось може означати записати на когось чи на щось. Зазвичай мова про те, що комусь у власність передають якісь ресурси (гроші, майно тощо), наприклад, йому нарахували запрлатню. Але не виключаю можливості застосовувати це слово й при приписуванні негативних речей (йому нарахували стільки-то гривень штрафу/боргів/тощо). Тобто ідея в тому, що щось (позитивне чи негативне) вносять на чийсь уявний баланс.

   Хоча в наш час моментальних безготівкових переказів межа між фіксацією грошового зобов'язання і його виконанням фактично стирається. Типу, якщо у Вас на банківській картці 100 грн — це вважати як «банк ще винен Вам ці 100 грн» чи як «Ви вже фактично маєте ці 100 грн»? Тому не виключаю, що значення «нарахувати комусь» з часом поступово зміниться від «записати на когось» до буквально «передати комусь».

Але іменник [нарахування](http://sum.in.ua/s/narakhuvannja) зазвичай застосовують лише до 3-го (бухгалтерського) значення дієслова нарах(ов)увати. Тобто нарахування — це, зазвичай, коли на чийсь рахунок вносять гроші. Або принаймні коли на когось записують якісь бухгалтерські сутності (активи абощо — я на цьому не дуже знаюся).

Comment: Дякую щиро, Sasha! Я мусив би зазначити, що мене цікавлять ці дієслова саме в фінансовому контексті. Я дуже вдячний Вам за загальні пояснення, але хотів дізнатися про різницю власне в цьому сенсі. Вибачте, що зразу не уточнив.

Comment: @SergeiKorn, а, в сенсі «зарахувати на карту чи нарахувати на карту»… Спочтаку мені здавалося, що, згідно зі словниками, у цьому випадку логічніше «нарахувати». Але, по-перше, словники лише відбивають життя і вони можуть дуже відставати (а на практиці «зарахувати на карту» дуже часто вживається). По-друге, я зрозумів, що «зарахувати на карту» теж логічно з погляду множини значень слова зарахувати. Як можна зарахувати людину до інституту (на завод тощо), так можна зарахувати гроші на карту. Тож, на жаль, не можу відповісти конретно.

Comment: @SergeiKorn, шкода, що Ви відразу не вточнили контекст запитання — можливо, знайшлися б інші охочі відповісти, з точнішою інформацією.

Comment: Мені Ваша відповідь у будь-якому разі дуже сподобалася. Дякую Вам!

Answer (score 3):

В контексті оподаткування, саме як використовуюється податковою службою України, значення цих слів має суттєву різницю.

Нараховано - це скільки податків нараховано для сплати, тобто лише підраховано і очікується для сплати (очікується для зарахування на рахунок).

Зараховано - це саме скільки податку сплачено (зараховано на рахунок).

[image]

Comment: _саме як використовуюється податковою службою України_ — можете навести приклад, бажано ланкою і витягом, на підтвердження цього?

Comment: Так відображаються нарахування податків в "[єдиному кабінеті платника податків](https://cabinet.tax.gov.ua/tax-account/)" в меню "стан розрахунків з бюджетом". [Скріншот](http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/Untitled.1635423422.png). Я не знаю вірно там вживаются ці слова чи ні, але при не правильному тлумаченні кардинально змінюється сенс на протилежний.